# Hilbert space for integral

Tags: functional-analysis

Find numbers $\alpha,\beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ so that the integral $$\int_{-1}^{1}|x^3-\alpha-\beta x-\gamma x^2|^2dx$$ is minimal.
Here I want to apply Hilbert space and projection lemma by considering the integral as the distance square between a point and a closed linear subspace. So how can I start my work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{M}$ is the subspace of polynomials $p(x)=\alpha + \beta x + \gamma x^2$, then you are looking for $p\in \mathcal{M}$ closest to $x^3$. Equivalently, $(x^3-p)\perp\mathcal{M}$, which gives equations
$$
       \int_{-1}^{1}(x^3-\alpha-\beta x-\gamma x^2)dx =0 \\
       \int_{-1}^{1}(x^3-\alpha-\beta x-\gamma x^2)xdx = 0 \\
       \int_{-1}^{1}(x^3-\alpha-\beta x-\gamma x^2)x^2dx = 0.
$$
That's 3 equations in the 3 unknowns $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.

Comment: Another way consists of constructing an ONB $\{u,v,w\}$ via Gram-Schmidt from $\{1,x,x^2\}$ for $M$ (which is easy since $1$ and $x$ are already orthogonal) and then simply projecting $x^3$ onto $M$: $P(x^3) = \langle x^3,u\rangle u + \langle x^3,v\rangle v + \langle x^3,w\rangle w$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : Not much is gained in this case. The second equation gives $\beta$ directly. The other two equations involve only $\alpha$, $\gamma$. If you want the Gram-Schmidt version, then can also look up the normalized Legendre polynomials and use them.

Comment: Yes. Also, when you have the projection, you have to go back to the coefficients which means to solve a 3x3 linear system anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As the Hilbert space, choose the span of the functions $x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3$ (on $(-1,1)$), equipped with the scalar product
$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx.
$$
The subspace $M$ that you want to project onto should be the span of $x^0,x^1,x^2$. In this setting you are looking for that function $f_0$ in $M$ which has the smallest distance to $x^3$.